# Packet generation in PCI PCIe devices

Tags: packet, crc, crc32, pci, pci-e

I have few questions on the PCI/PCIe Packet generation and the CRC generation and calculation. I have tried many searches but could not get the satisfactory answer. Please help me to understand the below points.

1.How does Packets(TLP, DLLP and PLLP) are formed in the PCI/PCIe System : For example lets say The CPU generates a Memory read/write from/to a PCIe device(here device is mapped into the memory). This request will be received by the PCI/PCIe Root Complex. The Root Complex will generate the TLP, also the DLLP and PLLP will be generated and appended to the TLP accordingly to form a PCI/PCIe pcket. This packet will be claimed by one of the root ports based on the MMIO address ranges. Each port on the Switch/Endpoints generate the DLLP and PLLP and pass it over to the next device on the link where it will be stripped and checked for errors.

Q.1 - Is it true that the packet generation/checking is fully done by the hardware ? What contribution does software do in packet generation as well as packet checking for errors on the receiving device ?

Q.2 - How does ECRC and LCRC are generated for a packet ? As the LCRC will be generated and checked at each PCI/PCIe device/ports and ECRC will be generated only once by requester which is root complex in our example. So Does the ECRC/LCRC generation/check are completely done by Hardware ? Can someone please explain with an example how the CRC/ECRC generated/check from the moment when the CPU generates a PCI read/write request ?

Q.3 - When we say that the "Transaction Layer", "DataLink Layer" and the "Physical Link Layer" generates the TLP, DLLP and PLLP respectively, Does this layers mean the Hardware or software layers ?

I think that if software will come into play each time when a packet, CRCs are generated/checked, It would slow down the data transfer. Also the Hardware can do these tasks much faster.

please correct me If I am wrong somewhere. I want to understand the above scenarios from HW vs SW points of view. Please help.

Comment: This is all done in hardware. Software merely executes a normal memory read or write instruction. (The other questions are off topic here.)

Comment: The PCIe core in located in the System Agent part of the CPU. It is in charge of building all the TLPs.